# Asking for input into a command for a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use bash to execute a terminal command and pass predefined input as arguments into said command.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR="openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr"
eval $STR

declare -a arr=('\n','\n','\n','\n','test.domain.com\n',"\n","\n", "\n", "\n")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

However, this doesn't execute the input into the command, it just executes the command, waits for me to mansually enter the input, and then prints the predfined input after.

Comment: Short version: `echo -e '\n\n\n\ntest.domain.com\n\n\n\n\n' | openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr`

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/